# Qt with multiple language on ARM9 based board

Tags: qt4, arm, embedded-linux, truetype, embedded-fonts

I am developing an application based an ARM9 based microprocessor using UBUNUTU (12.10).

My application is based on QT. I have cross compiled the QT4.8 with following command.

```
./configure -release --shared -no-qt3support -qt-sql-sqlite -plugin-sql-sqlite -exceptions -qt-libtiff -qt-libmng -qt-libjpeg -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-freetype -no-openssl -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake tools -no-phonon -qt-freetype -no-nis -no-opengl -no-cups -no-xcursor -no-xfixes -no-xrandr -no-xrender -no-xkb -no-sm -no-xinerama -no-xshape -no-separate-debug-info -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -embedded arm -depths 16  -little-endian -no-webkit -gtkstyle -fontconfig
```

I want multiple language UI.

I follow all the steps of,

> lupdate

&

> lrelease

utilities from QT. It generates TS file as well as QM files successfully.

This Application works on host machine but it does not work with the Target Board (ARM9 board). I could not get the multiple language UI on my LCD.

Comment: Did you install fonts with all of the *glyphs* for the languages?  If not, you will see empty boxes.  What do you see on the LCD?  What are you expecting?  Are you trying to use translations?  How exactly do you expect to see other languages?

Comment: I expect Gujarati language on the LCD. i am using gujarati_saral-1.ttf fonts for the same.I have used the Translators

Comment: Yes I want all the text with tr() must be converted into the Language what i want

Comment: i have used the export

Comment: So, if you display a Unicode string with Gujarati characters, it displays?  Correct?  Your issue is how to configure translations and get them working for Qt4/QWS. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have solved the problem.

I was not assigning a font to the Application.

Comment: Please 'accept' your answer, instead of writing *solved* in the title. It should be a check box below the number to the left of this answer.